# prevent submission of contact form to .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a website that has a contact form that send an email to me, the action that I want to achieve, is that when any user (it doesn't have to be logged in) submit that contact form prevent the submission of that form again for a period of time, this is to prevent spam.
I've been going through JWT tokens and thought about using a token to validate after the user submitted that form but I don't know if that's a possible solution and I wanted to know if there is another way of doing it.
I'm using C# Web Api for my backend and Angular 5 in my clientside app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [Google recapcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html).

Because you mention about Angular 5 on for Front-end development. You can use this [ngx-recaptcha](https://github.com/Enngage/ngx-captcha) to generate captcha on client-side, and validate the generated recapcha token on back-end.

The flow should be:

- User fills information to required form.
- User clicks on Submit button (implemented blind recaptcha).
- After user clicks on submit button, there should be one token generated by Google recaptcha service.
- Submit user information with recaptcha token in request.
- On back-end, validate the re-captcha token (using Google service with client secret, client id)
- If token valid, save the form information to database.
- If not, prevent the action.